# C++ beginner: Trying to incorporate two functions into one

Tags: c++

The addComplex() function is meant to accept two Complex objects and return a Complex object. The real and imaginary parts of the returned object should be the sum of the real and imaginary parts of the two objects passed to addComplex(). Of course, as you can see, I can only get it to return the sum of the real parts. How do I include the imaginary parts within the function?

This is homework that I've been working on for almost 2 hours and am coming up against a wall. Any help in the right direction is appreciated.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
// class declaration section
class Complex
{
  // friends list
  friend double addComplex(Complex&, Complex&);
  private:
    double real;
    double imag;
  public:
    Complex(double = 0, double = 0);  // constructor
    void display();
 };
 // class implementation section
Complex::Complex(double rl, double im)
{
  real = rl;
  imag = im;
}
void Complex::display()
{
  char sign = '+';
  if(imag < 0) sign = '-';
  cout << real << sign << abs(imag) << 'i';
  return;
}
// friend implementations
double addComplex(Complex &a, Complex &b)
{

  return (a.real + b.real);
}

int main()
{
  Complex a(3.2, 5.6), b(1.1, -8.4);
  double num;

  cout << "The first complex number is ";
  a.display();
  cout << "\n\nThe second complex number is ";
  b.display();

  cout << "\n\nThe sum of these two complex numbers is ";

  num = addComplex(a,b);
  Complex c(num);
  c.display();



    cout << "\n\nThis is the end of the program.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since this is a homework I will give only directives: Modify you function to return a complex, and define a complex that has what you want and return it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a Complex object, not a double.

As far as some code quality tips, you should create a constant accessor instead of making it a friend function. Also, the references should be const since you aren't modifying the inputs. And `using std` is often considered poor practice, though it's not so bad in a non-header file.

```
Complex addComplex(const Complex& a, const Complex& b)
{
  return Complex(a.real + b.real, a.imag + b.imag);
}
```

Comment: This wasn't the entire solution, but I didn't expect it to be since it was MY homework. Thank you for giving me enough info to help me solve it. I made the corrections you suggested, then (inspired by your suggestions) I noticed other items in my program that needed tweaking. It runs correctly now!

Answer (score 0):

```
Complex addComplex(Complex &a, Complex &b)
{
    return Complex(a.real + b.real, a.imag + b.imag);
}
```

You might also want to consider making the 'addComplex' function be an overload of the '+' operator.

Answer (score 0):

`addComplex` should return a `Complex` object:

```
Complex addComplex(const Complex &a, const Complex &b)
{

    /*Sum the real and imaginary parts, and use the constructor*/
    return Complex(a.real + b.real, a.imag + b.imag);
}
```

I've also made the parmaeters `const` reference types. This helps program stability since it means that the function cannot modify `a` and `b`.

Comment: static will make it only visible to this translation unit - probably not what was intended.

Comment: @Antimony: I've dropped `static`: yes, it does overcomplicate.